# Xamarin.Forms and iOS: how to combine UseSafeArea and a background image?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, background-image, safearealayoutguide

I've a question about the use of **safe area** for iOS.

I use a **background image** through a `RelativeLayout`, and I display a **form** on this background image. I use a `margin` for iOS on the form's container: this works fine, but the render on a **iPhone X** is not very nice.

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <Image Source="background.jpg" Opacity="0.75"
           Aspect="AspectFill"
           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint =
               "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
           RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint =
               "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" />

    <ScrollView RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint =
                    "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                 RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint =
                    "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">    
    <ScrollView.Margin>                
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 20, 0, 0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ScrollView.Margin>

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Header -->
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
            <fnc:HunterHeader />
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Form -->
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     Spacing="6" Margin="20">
            <!-- ... -->
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So I've tried to set the `UseSafeArea` to **true**, but I got top and bottom margins.

***Is it possible to fix this, and to combine UseSafeArea and a background image?
Or is there a way to add specific margin for the iPhone X only?***

Comment: set constraint to your ios views by enabling safe area option.

Comment: But I’ve enabled it, and this occurs margins before and after the background image.

Comment: Please make sure that you have given background image constraint to safe area and not the view

Comment: But how can we achieve this? Does this manage Android automatically?

Comment: I don't have an idea of xamarin programming.

Answer (score 6):

## Option 1 - Apply the Safe Area to A Specific Control rather than the Page

The safe area can be set on a specific control rather than the entire page. For example, the safe area values could be set to the margin or padding of the `ScrollView`. Orientation changes also need to be taken into account (if your app supports them).

**XAML**

```xaml
<RelativeLayout>

    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="background.png" 
           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
           RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"  />

    <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">    

        <StackLayout Margin="20, 0" Spacing="20">

            <!-- Header -->
            <StackLayout>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="50" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Form -->
            <StackLayout Spacing="20">
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" />
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" />
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" />
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" />
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" />
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" />
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code-Behind**

```cs
    private double width = 0;
    private double height = 0;
    private bool safeAreaSetInitially;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (!this.safeAreaSetInitially)
        {
            this.SetSafeAreaOnContentContainer();
            this.safeAreaSetInitially = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called

        if (Math.Abs(this.width - width) > double.Epsilon || Math.Abs(this.height - height) > double.Epsilon)
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            if (this.width > this.height)
            {
                // reconfigure for landscape if needed
            }
            else
            {
                // reconfigure for portrait if needed
            }

            // reset safe area on rotation as the landscape/portrait safe areas are different
            this.SetSafeAreaOnContentContainer();
        }
    }

    private void SetSafeAreaOnContentContainer()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            // set safe insets on content that you want to be within the safe area
            var safeInsets = On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
            safeInsets.Top += 20; // add any other custom design margin specific to iOS (the extra 20 came from the original XAML)
            this.scrollView.Margin = safeInsets;
        }
    }
```

**Result**

### [image]

## Option 2 - Use the [Page.BackgroundImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.backgroundimage?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Page_BackgroundImage) property

Depending on the requirements, another option is to just use the `BackgroundImage` property of the `Page` (it is not affected by the `On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true)` method). One gotcha with this approach is that the BackgroundImage is "tiled" in iOS. To get around this, create a custom `Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage` renderer that does not "tile" the [BackgroundImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.backgroundimage?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Page_BackgroundImage). Here is an [example](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89781/xamarin-forms-ios-prevent-tile-style-background-image-for-contentpage).